# La du signifoj de “lasta”

Tags: word-meaning

Se mi diras la jenan ekzemplan frazon:

> Ĉi tiu estas la lasta numero de la revuo Kontakto

ŝajnas ke povus esti du signifoj:

1. Tiu numero estas tiu kiu eldoniĝis antaŭ la plej mallonga tempo.
2. Neniam plu estos alia numero de Kontakto post ĉi tiu.

Ŝajnas al mi ke la distingo inter la du signifoj estas tre grava. Ĉu oni markas la diferencon nur per kunteksto, aŭ ĉu estas aliaj manieroj por precizigi tion? Mi kredas ke en la angla oni uzus du apartajn vortojn *latest* kaj *last*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi konsentas, ke la distingo inter la du signifoj estas grava.

Kaj kvankam la signifo de *lasta* en la senco de "latest" estas Zamenhofa kaj bone dokumentita (kp. signifon 2 en [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#lasta)), laŭ mi kaj multaj aliaj parolantoj ĝi estas evitinda. Fakte ĝi estas klare enhave distingebla de la tri aliaj signifoj de *lasta*, kiujn oni povas resumi per "estanta ĉe la kompletigita fino de vico de aĵoj, adoj aŭ rilatoj".
Anstataŭe oni uzas ekz. *plej freŝa/aktuala* (numero de revuo ktp.) aŭ *pasinta* (naskiĝtagdatreveno), *ĵusa* (okazintaĵoj) k.s.

Do, por efektive respondi vian demandon, oni povas ne fari la distingon inter "last" kaj "latest" en Esperanto, uzante nur *lasta*, sed estas konsilinde fari ĝin, kvankam unuopa alternativa vorto por la dua signifo mankas.

Answer (score 2):

Laŭ mia sperto, oni ofte uzas "plej freŝa" por la nuna / plej nova eldono de io, aŭ la plej nova verko de iu.

Guglante "plej freŝa" vi trovos multajn ekzemplojn tiusencajn.